# Пагинации страниц и проблема с LIMIT и OFFSET [PHP+SQL]

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Доброго времени суток. Интересует такой момент, для создания пагинации с помощью PHP и MySQL. Я пытаюсь в табличном виде осуществить вывод пользователей отсортировав при этом их по времени последнего посещения. Но когда я пытаюсь сделать OFFSET с использованием LIMIT то само смещение не работает. Что сможете посоветовать в таком случае? Спасибо!

```
  $sql  = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1 
    ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET '.$page;
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $info1[$index] =    $row;
        $index++;
    }
```

Comment: потому что $page * 10 (если у вас 10 элементов на странице). причем изначальная страница должна быть нулевой

Comment: $sql  = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10*('.intval($page).' -1)';

Comment: и почему Вы $page тупо вклеиваете в запрос ручками? у Вас же mysqli - используйте связывание переменных.